# Encoders for collections in apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-encoders

Is there a way to create `Encoders` for collection type in apache spark. I tried below approach but it does not work.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class CollectionEntity<T>  implements Serializable {

    private T collectionData;

    public T getCollectionData(){
        return collectionData;
    }

    public void setCollectionData(T inputCollectionData){
        this.collectionData = inputCollectionData;
    }
}
```

Then I created a child class

```
public class CollectionEntityForStringArray extends CollectionEntity<String[]> {
}
```

But when i try to create the Encoder as below it is showing compilation error

```
Encoder<CollectionEntity<String[]>> collectionEncoder = Encoders.bean(CollectionEntityForStringArray.class);
```

**Incompatible types. Required Encoder> but bean was inferred to Encode. Incompatible equality constraint.**